# Ways to do an SVN merge with tree conflicts where files have moved

Tags: svn

I am about to do an SVN merge, reintegrating a branch back into the trunk.

Some files changed in the branch, which have been moved within the trunk, so I'm expecting tree conflicts.

What's the best procedure to follow to do the merge successfully and be able to compare the original (moved) trunk files with the updated branch files (which reside in a directory that has been removed on the trunk)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should first merge your trunk with your branch in order to "synchronize" your branch with the trunk;
2. Apply all modifications made in your branch to the moved files;
3. Test, before commiting your branch;
4. Merge your branch in the trunk;

```
    // Step 1
    svn merge -rX:Y url/to/trunk path/to/branch
    ...
    // Step 4 
    svn merge -rA:B --reintegrate url/to/branch path/to/trunk
```

**Note**: `--reintegrate` works only for svn version >= 1.5

good luck.